# Only move last n commits to other branch

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

My structure currently looks like this:

```
master   A-B-C-D-E-F
                \
                 \
branch2           D2 - D3 - D4
```

And I want to move the last two commits (`D3` and `D4`) from `branch2` to master without moving `D2`. So it should look like this:

```
master   A-B-C-D-E-F-D3-D4
                \
                 \
branch2           D2
```

How can this be achieved?

*Please consider that the master-branch already exists - I have already seen several answers merging to new branches but this is not valid here.*

Comment: You could `cherry-pick` commits from `branch2` into `master` and then undo the last two commits in `branch2`.

Comment: `Please consider that the master-branch already exists` what's the intent of this comment? It's not clear why merging branch2 into master would be 'invalid'.

Comment: To clear this up: `D2` should not be in master and I do not want to create a new branch for the last two commits and instead move `D3` and `D4` directly to master.

Comment: What you're asking for means "rewriting history" as it means removing existing commits from your repo and then re-introducing them elsewhere.  Making these sorts of changes is both technically and logically wrong.  Technically, it will screw up existing clones that contain the initial D3 and D4 commits.  Logically, it means losing information about what happened.  What you may want instead is `D-E-F-D3a-D4a` and `D2-D3-D4-!D4-!D3` where `!D4` is a revert of `D4` and `D4a` is a cherry-picked commit.

Comment: @CryptoFool the op asked how to cherry pick a commit (without using that term)... how is that 'technically and logically wrong'? I think you're reading into the question something that's not there, of course the hash of D3 will change when it's applied to a different parent commit.

Comment: ...note that what I suggest is what the accepted answer gives you.  It doesn't give you anything like what you depict in your question, as commits D3 and D4 continue to exist.

Comment: @AD7six - It's the fact that the original D3 and D4 commits have been removed from the repo that is wrong.

Comment: k, I disagree - there is nothing in the question saying that branch2 is a public branch (`removed from the repo` assuming this means branch) - and even if it is there are plenty of scenarios where rewriting history is no problem at all. We can agree to disagree :).

Comment: @AD7six - I agree with you if "branch2" is a private branch or if commits D3 and D4 have not yet been pushed.  But that was not stated in the question.  I guess I should have made my statement less strong than to suggest it is always wrong to do a rollback...a rewriting of history.  It remains true, however, as you point out yourself in your comment, that the accepted answer does not lead to the state of the repo depicted in the question.

Comment: Please note that the way the branches are labelled is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Janez Kuhar's comment, what you'll do is

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick D3
git cherry-pick D4
```

where `D3` and `D4` are the shas for the commits.

Since we don't want to have duplicate commits and you indicated that you want to remove those commits from branch2, we then do:

```
git revert D3^..D4
```

again where `D3` and `D4` are the shas for the commits.

Comment: To achieve exactly what's depicted in the question would be `git checkout branch2; git reset --hard D2`. Reverting is valid (even preferred) but it's worth calling out that that would mean if/when branch2 is merged into master, D3 and D4 would _also_ be reverted in master. There's also no problem/complication with leaving D3 and D4 in branch2, so it depends on the overall intent.

Comment: I agree with @AD7six - This doesn't give the result the OP is asking for, but it is probably the more correct solution.  See my comment on the question itself.  What AD7six says about later merging `branch2` into `master` is true as well.